# Unable to center my UILabel over my custom view

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uilabel, constraints

I'm creating a tap war game and I added to custom views to my app, a redView and blueView. Both views take up half of the screen. I'm trying to position a label over each of the two views to keep track of scores (labels are called "topviewLabel" and "bottomViewLabel"), specifically in the center, but the labels appear in the top left corners of their respective views and won't center properly. I create the views and set their constraints programmatically and then add labels to the redView or blueView, I'm doing this all programmatically. I'll leave the code below, let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 206/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    redView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(redView)

    let redviewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.height / 2)
    ]

    view.addConstraints(redviewConstraints)

    let blueView = UIView()
    blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)
    blueView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(blueView)

    let blueViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.height / 2)
    ]

    view.addConstraints(blueViewConstraints)


    let topViewLabel = UILabel()
    topViewLabel.frame = CGRect(x: redView.frame.size.width / 2, y: redView.frame.size.height / 2, width: 80, height: 80)
    topViewLabel.text = "30"
    topViewLabel.textAlignment = .center
    topViewLabel.font.withSize(30)
    topViewLabel.textColor = .white
    topViewLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    topViewLabel.center = redView.center
    redView.addSubview(topViewLabel)
    redView.bringSubview(toFront: topViewLabel)

    let bottomViewLabel = UILabel()
    bottomViewLabel.frame = CGRect(x: blueView.frame.width / 2, y: blueView.frame.height / 2, width: 80, height: 80)
    bottomViewLabel.center = blueView.center
    bottomViewLabel.text = "20"
    bottomViewLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    blueView.addSubview(bottomViewLabel)
    blueView.bringSubview(toFront: bottomViewLabel)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **paulvs** said, in viewDidLoad your subviews do not have their frames set yet. So when, for example, you try to set your label frame

```
topViewLabel.frame = CGRect(x: redView.frame.size.width / 2, y: redView.frame.size.height / 2, width: 80, height: 80)
```

redview.frame has width and height 0.

These parameters will be calculated properly only in layoutSubviews.

So you can either set you labels frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method 
or (which I would do) use constraints for it. Something like

```
let topViewLabelConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: topViewLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: topViewLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
]
redView.addConstraints(topViewLabelConstraints)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I'm getting this in the console window UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000094370 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7fad82410640'30'.midY == 284   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000092c00 UIView:0x7fad82403180.height == 284   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093dd0 UILabel:0x7fad82410640'30'.centerY == UIView:0x7fad82403180.centerY   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093dd0 UILabel:0x7fad82410640'30'.centerY == UIView:0x7fad82403180.centerY

Comment: When I start the app up the label is centered but is cut off halfway at the bottom of the red view

Comment: When you add constraints from code you often want to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of constrained view to false, as you did with your red and blue views. So adding 'topViewLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false' should help

Answer (score 0):

A `UIView` doesn't have its correct frame size right after adding constraints, you need to add:

```
blueView.setNeedsLayout()
blueView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Now `blueView`'s frame is set.

Comment: It still didn't fix the issue, any other ideas?